# Change Image when an action is performed

Tags: java, actionlistener

How can I change my images when an action is performed? My images are stored in the project.

Declared images

```
image = new ImageIcon ("1.jpg");
image2 = new ImageIcon ("3.jpg");
image3 = new ImageIcon ("2.jpg");
picLabel = new JLabel(image);
```

ActionListener Class

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    if(e.getSource().equals(A)) {
        image = new ImageIcon ("1.jpg");
        //picLabel = new JLabel(image); didn't work
    } else if(e.getSource().equals(B)) {
        image = new ImageIcon ("2.jpg");
        //picLabel = new JLabel(image2); didn't work
    } else if(e.getSource().equals(C)) {        
        image = new ImageIcon ("3.jpg");
        //picLabel = new JLabel(image3); didn't work
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you assign a new `JLabel` to the `picLabel` label, you create a new object that is not part of your UI. The existing `JLabel` in your UI is referenced by `picLabel`, so calling

```
picLabel.setIcon(image);
```

should set the Icon for the existing `JLabel`.

Answer (score 1):

You must call

```
picLabel.setIcon(image);
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep a reference to `picLabel` in your class and in the action listener call `picLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon("Whatever.jpg"));` to change the picture.